# Can I do a regression with 3 independent observations and inside of each several nested (thus dependent) observations?

Tags: r, regression, independence, nested-models

I have an (ecological/soil science) experiment with a multiple nested design with 3 real independent observations (sites with different caracteristics), and several dependent observations within them (3 observations or blocks in each site, with nested factors and repeated measures, as described in figure).

[image]

The first attempt I've decided to do is 3 sepparated mixed models rm anova (my predictor variables are categorical), but I am now wondering if it is plausible as a complementary analysis, to make a general regression using a covariate with such nested caracteristics. I am not sure if having only 3 real independent observations with several dependent (pseudorreplicated) values is reliable to do a regression.

I am an RStudio user (using the nlme package).

Thanks in advance!